Why is SymmetrizedArray taking so much memory?
The context is: I take the tensor product of 2 totally symmetric tensors of rank 8, in 2 dimensions(in this case there are only 9 independent components):
values1 = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {9}];
values2 = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {9}];
tensorProd = KroneckerProduct[values1, values2] // Flatten;

The vectors values1and values2 represent the vector of LI components in canonical order, that is, they are the numbers corresponding to the output of
SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[ConstantArray[2,8], Symmetric[All]]

Following that, I generate the list of LI components of  tensorProd:
comps = SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[ConstantArray[2, 8], 
   Symmetric[All]];

tensorProdIndComp = 
  Outer[({#1, #2} // Flatten) &, comps, comps, 1] // Flatten[#, 1] &;

and create the rules associating values to components for the input of SymmetrizedArray:
rules =  MapThread[
       Rule,
   {tensorProdIndComp, tensorProd}
   ];

However, when I try to construct the Array I get a memory issue:
SymmetrizedArray[rules, 
 ConstantArray[2, 
  16], {{Symmetric[Range[8]]}, {Symmetric[Range[9, 16]]}}]

SymmetrizedIndependentComponents::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.

SymmetrizedIndependentComponents::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.

This sounds weird to me because the full tensor is not at all heavy, 2^16 = 65 536 numerical components is not that much.
Does anyone know how to deal with that, to recover the full array in a manner that is as efficient as SymmetrizedArray? For reference I am using a M1 MacBook, 8 Gb of Ram.

Using 14.0 on Intel machine with 32 GB, I get the same error.  I also get the iconized output indicating the symmetry order is 1 625 702 400.

@Lexington1776 I had no idea it was that bad, I thought that with 16 GB the problem would probably be solved. I got the same iconized output with the symmetry order.
